# Making a simple array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

A very, very simple C# question.

I want to create a normal little array of a type that is another class.

bits of the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        classA[] test;
        test = new classA[2];
        Console.Write(test[0].getName());


class classA
{
    string name;
    public classA()
    {
        this.name = "zup";
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
```

Why wont it let me ?

Comment: You don't fill the array.
Normally `test[0].getName()` should lead to a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an array of a reference type like that, the array is initialised with nulls - no actual objects are constructed (other than the array itself).

Therefore you need to explicitly create each element of your array.

For your example, you will need to do this:

```
classA[] test;
test = new classA[2];
test[0] = new classA();
test[1] = new classA();
```

Note that if you were using a *value* type such as a struct or a primitive type (int, double, char etc) this would not be necessary.

You often write a loop to initialise an array, so again for your code sample:

```
classA[] test;
test = new classA[2];

for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; ++i)
    test[i] = new classA();
```

Answer (score 2):

You create an array of type `ClassA`, but don't initalize the elements, so the elements in the array are all `null`. To make a simple test array, with content, use an array initializer instead:

```
var test = new ClassA[] { new ClassA(), new ClassA() };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as below

```
test = new classA[2].Select(c=>new classA()).ToArray();
```

after you call `new classA[2]` you have null items in the array. above code will add new ClassA object to each array item. Now you can call `Console.Write(test[0].getName());` without exception